# Oracle database syncing hardware solution?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-golden-gate

I am newer one on Oracle system. I am facing to a problem related Oracle database syncing.

We have 2 databases(A and B). Database A is synced to database B via Oracle GoldenGate. When too many records insert into database A, Oracle GoldenGate falls down.

Can you please suggest another solution for this issue ? We interest in physical hardware solutions if it is available.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Golden Gate is used for logical replication. Hardware replication is a physical kind of replication, like Oracle Data Guard. There will be a reason for the choice for logical replication. If not, go for Oracle Data Guard, which is very efficient and robust.